# embed a drupal gmap view on other sites

Tags: php, drupal, google-maps, embed, drupal-gmap

anyone know how to compose an embed-snippet of the outputted map from a gmap view made with the gmap module in Drupal - for use on other sites? Like the link that appears on top of any map on maps.google.com?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to do that with [Embed widgets](http://drupal.org/project/embed_widgets).

Comment: You might have better luck with the Web Widgets module ( http://drupal.org/project/web_widgets) as it is more Views-specific.

Comment: actually, I managed to get Embed Widgets to work - thanks a lot for your suggestions!